# Does God work on the basis of Laws?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, parvati

I would like to know whether God works on the basis of certain Laws. For example, consider the chanting of mantras. People chant them in order to invoke certain deities. However, some people can read them wrongly (by mistake aka mispronouncing) unconsciously. People say that when we do so, God will not be pleased or you might invoke wrong entities like Rakshasas.

Why should it happen? If the devotee incorrectly reads a mantra unconsciously why should he be punished for that? He has done it unknowingly, doesn't god know it?

Next, people say Lord Shiva likes Bel leaves, Lord Vishnu likes tulsi leaves. But it is said that there is nothing god specifically likes because everything is a manifestation of him. Can it be Bel leaves or leaves of some other plants.

Does God work on the basis of certain laws or act independently preserving the core laws? All of the Gods laws or deeds cannot be known by any Sage is right, but still can we at least assume that there are certain laws for him on which he does those deeds.

For example, courage is positive energy and we are able to do things when we have it. When we are frightened we will not be able to do them. No matter whether his devotee is frightened or not, won't he receive help from the God?

Discourage and fear are negative energies and those who don't have it are said to be dearer to the Supreme being (as from Bhagavad Gita).

Doesn't the man with fear get his desire fulfilled?

Comment: God is above and beyond most laws and so are we, in our most perfected state of consciousness. Sri Ramakrishna Paramhansa said that Laws and rules can be compared to a fence that has been placed around a plant when it is in growing state. The fence ensures that animals do not graze on the plant and kill it. Also it makes it easy to maintain the plant from time to time. However once the plant is fully grown then the tree itself outgrows the fence. Similarly once our consciousness matures we realize that we are ourselves above and beyond all Laws.

Comment: Why does God appear to follow some laws at some times whereas at other times He doesn't follow any laws? This is because God encourages us to follow laws so long as it helps us to grow, how does He encourage? By following them Himself and leading the way. But at times when the law itself becomes the burden and causes stranglation of our growth He encourages to come out of the laws by break free of these laws. How does He encourage? By breaking the laws and showing that we are above and beyond the laws. He leads the way externally and also inspires us internally. He is the prime mover of us.

Comment: Yes God follows the law. But it is not our country law. It is the divine law. Fate of a soul is decided by some principle which is set by God. He is the most serious follower of own divine law & because of that he takes incarnation. In same time he is above the law, means the country made law, & within law, own made law. As per his own law he punished us. He need not wait for your country law. If he wants he can kill anybody,Nobody can imprison him & if he wants then he can bring life back to anybody no body can stop him indicates that he can acts with his own law. He kills the giants & he was

Comment: Courage and fear, are two sides of the same coin.This is what Yogeshwara Sri Krishna discourses about in the Bhagavad Gita-it is summed up as-Samatvam Yogam Uchate.

Answer (score 2):

Fear is tamasic. A man with a rajasic attitude gets his desires fulfilled.

God (the Supreme) is above all law; law only exists in maya, in this universe. If you are chanting mantras to gain some result within this universe, the mantra is not directed to God, it is directed to those forces or gods in this universe that can fulfill those desires. And then yes, the mantra has to be intoned and pronounced correctly.

If you are making an offering to God - and it is being done with love, then God does not care if you make a mistake, God only wants love (Gita 18. 57-58, and Gita 9. 26)

Comment: what rajasic means?

Comment: Gita Ch. 18. verses 31, 34.

Comment: what does it mean by Lord Shiva likes Bel leaves while God cannot have likes/dislikes?

Comment: Also we see for some people who are frightened, they get their desires fulfilled too. God might be helping them? Isn't it?

Comment: God helps no one in fulfilling desires. You help yourself in fulfilling desires. You create your own karma.

Comment: Then why do people go to temples and ask the god to fulfill their desires? And they see they get them done. Also, some things will not be under our control, but still we see them happening (in order for our desire to be fulfilled). How does it happen then without the aid of god?

Comment: Most people. Most people are materialists who want the things of this world and follow popular custom. They go to temples - not out of Love of God - but to beg for more materialistic things. Gita (II. 42-44). Be careful what you wish for...because you will get it. It only creates more karma. For every person who says that they have gotten what they asked for in a temple, there are 10 that do not get. But those ten will get, but maybe in the next life or in 2 lives, or etc...You yourself create your own karma, you yourself will fulfill your own wishes.

Comment: And when the wish is fulfilled, perhaps you no longer want it or need it, but still you will have to pay for the consequent karma it generates...